# Algo to print permutation of numbers for Phone Keypad

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, logic, combinations, permutation

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

Find all the permutations of a given letter upto n max character.
A letter successor can be from the same line horizontally or vertically.

Eg. For 1 next letter will be 2,3,4 and 7
Similarly for 8 it will be 2,5,7 and 9

**Input:**

n - No of max characters in permutations (1...10)

x - First digit (1...9)

**Output:**
All the permutations starting with given digit and of length n

**Example:**
1.
Input:.n = 3, x = 2

Output: 212, 213, 214, 217, 231, 232, 236, 239, 254, 256, 252, 258, 282, 285, 287, 289

2. n = 5, x = 7

Output: 7123654, 7852136, 7893693, 7147147, 7463258 and so on

For upto n = 7, it works fine but for n > 7, code runs infinitely.
Any optimised answer to my solution

```
var array: [String] = []
var n = 7
func calculate(digit: Int, previous: String) {
    var new = previous + "\(digit)"
    if new.count == n {
        array(new)
        return
    }
    for val in values[digit] ?? [] {
        calculate(digit: val, previous: new)
    }
}

calculate(digit: 2, previous: "")
```

Comment: The number of resulting output strings is 4^n, which obviously grows pretty fast: at 7 it's ~16k, 8 is ~65k, etc. The first optimization that comes to mind is [memoizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) substrings (maybe pairs or triples?), though I'm not sure how much runtime that would actually save. Assuming you don't care about the order if the returned results, you could also try parallelization, but a simple/naive implementation of that would quickly spawn far more threads than your CPU has cores.

Comment: So when have only n=10, how do I perform this as memoization won't be applicable in this case. Maybe by using graphs to traverse multiple paths at same time may help. But I am not sure how the implementation will be like.